# How do I speed up digamma calculation in big sparse matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, gamma-function

I have two large numpy matrices, `X` and `r` (appr. 5500x3500). I need to calculate `digamma(X+r)` and `digamma(r)`, which I do with `scipy.special.psi`. The calculation happens in the gradient function that I am using for a fit by gradient descent. During optimization the gradient function is going to be called a lot of times, so it is imperative that it runs fast. Now, to the actual question:

- `digamma(r)` takes ~11s to run
- `digamma(X+r)` takes ~50s to run

out of curiosity I ran some other examples:

- `digamma(X.astype(np.float64))`, takes ~1min to run
- `digamma(X)`, takes ~5-6min to run

**why is that happening, and what can I do to improve runtimes?**

- `X` contains integers (`numpy.int64`) from 0 to 164.
- `r` contains floats (`numpy.float64`) from 0. to ~4.6.
- X is very sparse (about 75% of it is 0).
- r is not sparse (about 10% of it is 0)

EDIT: corrected `X.as_float`

Comment: numpy arrays and matrices do not have an `as_float` attribute.  Do you mean `X.astype(np.float64)`?

Comment: yeah, I just didn't want to write it like that for the sake of brevity. Thanks for pointing it out, might as well edit.

Comment: So `digamma(X)` alone runs slower than `digamma(X+r)`? That's quite curious.

Comment: The docs for `digamma` hints that computation complexity depends on the variable value. In quick time tests `digamma(np.ones(1000))` is significantly slower than anything else.  The wiki page for this function also shows considerable computational complexity.

Comment: it is quite puzzling... When I simulated matrices of similar sparsity to `X` and `r` with `scipy.sparse` and filled them with values from the corresponding ranges, they both needed close to 1 minute to run. vOv

A glance at the source code of digamma confirms that it has different approaches for different value ranges. My working hypothesis is that the makeup of `X` and `r` are uniquely suited (or not) for digamma calculations. I just have to swallow the computational cost for now :(

Comment: I've run into the same problem and opened an [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8127) about it.  In the meantime, the scipy implementation of digamma is probably best avoided.  For an alternative, [here](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/py_src/asa103/asa103.html)'s a good place to start.

Comment: thanks a lot! Will definitely check it out!

Comment: Looks like it'll be improved in the next release: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/8129

Comment: yeah, I was following the thread on github. Glad to see that it is getting improved! If you or @hpaulj want to post this as an answer I can mark the question as closed :)